# Unable to download large files .NET Core Mvc Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and running it with IIS.

When I download a file from below controller method:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class FileController : ControllerBase
{    
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
      return PhysicalFile("C:\\Temp\\LargeFile.pdf", "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
    }
}
```

With a 160Mb file it works perfectly.

With a 277mb file, the HTTP reponse has also code 200 (no exeception raised in debug) however the "content-length" is 0...

It there any limit on the reponse size?

Comment: how do you know that the response has code of 200 and is it quick? Some exception or error are not raised and breaks the code execution but it should be still printed in the *Output* window while debugging. I don't think there is any limit in response size, some custom code may do something with it however.

Comment: @King King: You were right, it does not seems to have a reponse size limit. The issue was actually coming from one of our custom middleware in the pipeline which was not supporting large files because tried to read the request response into a MemoryStream... Thank you for your input.